# flutter html Runtime bug

Tags: flutter, error-handling, runtime, cross-platform, openai-api

I have tried to make a connection with Open AI API and called the 2 of them 3 times 1 for 2 and another for 1 time the API doesn't possesses any error or request calls so i don't know why this error is getting showed.

**
*flutter doctor -v output***

```
PS C:\Users\DC\Desktop\my_voiceassistant> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2134], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.3.10 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 135454af32 (9 months ago), 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
    • Engine revision 3316dd8728
    • Dart version 2.18.6
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\DC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.0)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.1.32210.238
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at D:\android_studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\DC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.70.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64 • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2134]

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

***Debug console output***

```
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\DC\Desktop\my_voiceassistant\.dart_tool\flutter_build\99298210eb4d63a485fe99bd982d2307\kernel_snapshot.d
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/speech_to_text-6.1.1/lib/speech_to_text_web.dart:3:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' as html;
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:13:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'

import 'dart:html' as html;
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' as html;
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/utils.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';

       ^
U
nhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; me
ssage=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)

#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.d
art:659:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:799:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:625:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1451:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
2

#
5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:10:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
4

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assemble Debug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have tried to run with this error and tried to get rid of it by removing dart.html from pub cache file but it doesn't worked and there's a Git hub repo from where i get knowledge but still didn't get my error solved there's another stack overflow request there with the same error for different request & I have also closed ways for my app to reach for web but still didn't get my error solved if possible can anyone help me

thanks for wasting your precious time and going through my error.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to remove dart.html from my 'OpenAPIService.dart' and that worked for me
I am getting this as the reference that i have created with URI works different with different platforms and for web platform, I have to write a code with source and more prompts

if anyone have solved this error before and have something else as a solution in mind or logic in mind feel free to answer this block

much respect for wasting your precious time till here.<3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).